# Xamarin forms WebView cookies cleared when app closed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have Xamarin Forms WebView app for android. I'm able to use the app perfectly fine on first login. But if i re-open the app WebView cookies clear and user need to login again.
I want that the user does not need to log in after they have logged in once, even if they close the application.
Here is my code:

```
 var wbURL = "https://www.example.com/login/";
 webrowser.Source = wbURL;
```

Comment: I added a possible solution for Android as well. Are you using custom renderers for your Webview? Are you running some code in them that might affect the cookie persistence?

Comment: Within the app, make it possible for user to logout, then log back in - without closing the webview or the app. This is to verify that it isn't the server causing the cookies to be invalidated. If that fails, then it isn't webview - its the server not recognizing that the cookies are still valid. if that succeeds, then indeed somehow webview or app is dropping them, as you currently suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android, cookies should be stored automatically, unless you delete them manually using a custom renderer.

For iOS, you can save cookies and restore them later on, something like this:

Save cookies (Call this method after the user is logged in, this code is placed into the **WebView custom renderer**):

```
public async Task SaveCookies()
{
    // For iOS < 10, cookies are saved in NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage(), coojies should work withouth this
    if (!UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        var cookies = await Configuration.WebsiteDataStore.HttpCookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
        var cachedCookies = cookies.Select(c => new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain)
            {
                Secure = c.IsSecure,
                Version = Convert.ToInt32(c.Version)
            }).ToList();

            //TODO: Save the cachedCookies into app cache. You can create a service in the shared project
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
           
    }
}
```

Restore cookies (Call this in the WebView custom renderer OnElementChanged method):

```
var store = WKWebsiteDataStore.NonPersistentDataStore;
await RestoreCookies(store);

private async Task RestoreCookies(WKWebsiteDataStore store)
{
    // For iOS < 10, cookies are saved in NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage(), coojies should work withouth this
    if (!UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (store == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    await ClearCookies(store);
    var storedCookies = //TODO: Retreive cookies from where you sotred them

    foreach (Cookie cookie in storedCookies)
    {
        await store.HttpCookieStore.SetCookieAsync(new NSHttpCookie(cookie));
    }
}

private async Task ClearCookies(WKWebsiteDataStore store)
{
    var cookies = await store.HttpCookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
    if (cookies?.Any() ?? false)
    {
        foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in cookies)
        {
            await store.HttpCookieStore.DeleteCookieAsync(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you have problems on Android as well, try this code in your WebView custom renderer:

```
 var cookieManager = CookieManager.Instance;
 cookieManager.SetAcceptCookie(true);
 cookieManager.AcceptCookie();
 cookieManager.Flush(); // Forces cookie sync
```

Comment: NOTE: OP says they are having this problem **on Android**. I'm not familiar with webview - do you have any ideas what might be wrong? Or add comments to the question about other info OP could provide to help figure out what is happening?

Comment: Oh right, I misread. I did work with WebViews and I never had cookie persistence problems on Android before. I'll edit the post with some code, thanks!